# Visualforce Apexpage 'AJAX' like response

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I have written a VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="DocumentObjects">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Document objects">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageblocksection >
        <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!migrate}" value="Migrate"/>
        </apex:pageblocksectionitem>        
        <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                  <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxresult" layout="block">
            Result: {!migrateStatus}
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblocksectionItem>
    </apex:pageblocksection>                

        <apex:pageBlock title="Document">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!documents}" var="doc">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!doc.id}">{!doc.name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!doc.Description}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!doc.ContentType}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Attachment">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!attachments}" var="att">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!att.id}">{!att.name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!att.Description}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!att.ContentType}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>      

        <apex:pageblocksection >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!migrate}" value="Migrate"/>
        </apex:pageblocksection> 
    </apex:pageBlock> 
  </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

This is the Controller class:

```
public with sharing class DocumentObjects {

    private String migrateStatus;
    private List<Document> documentList;
    private List<Attachment> attachmentList;

    public DocumentObjects()
    {
        queryDocument();
        queryAttachment();
    }

 ...

    ...

    public List<Document> getDocuments() {
        return documentList;
    }

    public List<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        return attachmentList;
    }


    // Button action
    public String getMigrateStatus()
    {
        return migrateStatus;
    }

    public void migrate()
    {
        LocalAccess client = new LocalAccess();
        client.setObjects(this);
        migrateStatus = client.status();
    }
}
```

What I intend to do is to get regular page like updates in the LocalAccess class. Say for example, there are about 10 documents, the LocalAccess class operates on the list and then updates information through apexmessage like:

Document1 updated

Document2 updated <a few minutes later>

....

However, the reality is that when I click the migrate button, the page takes a longer time to refresh and the page response is displayed as

Document1 updated

Document2 updated

....

in entirety (The whole update is displayed only when the entire list is processed). How do I proceed to view information like an AJAX style response in a VF page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism supported on the platform for this type of long-polling asynchronous update to the UI is the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/).

There is also a walk-through from Salesforce on getting started with an example of it: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API

You will likely need to change your code to use an asynchronous method (`@future`) to process the items in the list. Essentially you're going to fire off the work to be done and use the Streaming API to monitor its progress in the VF page.

---

Alternatively, if the Streaming API doesn't work out you can probably put together a solution that uses the [`<apex:actionPoller>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm) where it's action runs a query to determine the status of the records which were initially dispatched with an `@future` method call.